# What is the difference between an infinite set of 1 dollar bills and an infinite set of 20 dollar bills?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, direct-sum

Even though both sets approach infinity at different increments, do they eventually approach infinity at the same value at the same degree? Or is the second set of infinite 20 dollar bills 20 times larger than the infinite 1 dollar bills?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question unless you say what "infinite" means. There are many different kind of infinite in mathematics.

Comment: There are different cardinalities of infinite sets, so it depends on 'how infinite' each of those sets are. If you want them to be countably-infinite, then that trivially answers the question for you.

Comment: The cardinality of a set has **nothing to do** with what its elements are or stand for: the fact that you are considering sets of \$1 bills and \$20 bills has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What kind of difference do you mean?  As sets, the difference is the set of $1$ dollar bills because the two sets are disjoint.  The value of the money in each set is not well defined, so the difference is not well defined.  Please think about your question and clarify.

Comment: @RossMillikan, by difference I mean the value of money in both sets. I was wondering whether one set would be larger than the other or if they would be essentially the same, but I realize from the responses there's no conclusive answer.

Comment: Fundamentally, you cannot add up an infinite list of numbers.  You can add any finite set of numbers.  When we write a sum of an infinite set of numbers, we need to appeal to taking the limit of finite sums as the number of terms increases without bound.  That can only be done when the sum converges, which is does not do here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both sets are countable,they have the same cardinality and they both are in one-to-one correspondence with the set of natural numbers. The truth of matter is that they will never reach infinity in finite time.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, $f(n)=n$ (the amount of money in $n$ bills each worth $\$1$) and $g(n)=20n$ are both functions that "tend to infinity" in the sense that if you want the output to be greater than some large number $M$ than you just have to require that the input is larger than some number $N$.

I think the answer(s) to your question are a matter of perspective.

- Since they both tend to infinity, they're kind of the same in that way. Relatedly, in a Calculus class you might write that the sum of the values of $f$ and $g$ are both "$\infty$".
- But for $n\ge1$, $g(n)/f(n)=20$, so $g(n)$ could be said to grow ("approach infinity"?) twenty times as fast.
- However, they both grow *linearly*. Using "[Big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)", we could write $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ to express the idea that they grow at roughly the same speed.

Comment: If the downvoter (or anyone else) would like to elaborate on an issue they had with my answer, I'd be curious to know and happy to address it if possible. If desired, I can be contacted privately via the link in my profile.